# Right sidebar height 100% not working

Tags: css

Firstly I did many search and all the answers suggest to set html and body height as 100%, so I did so but didn't work.

The problem is, the body background is gray (#e5e5e5), where right sidebar may change its background color (#fff, or anything else)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzm0mf9d/

In my design:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 300px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is, right side background is as high as view port. No matter how long the content is.

```
<div class="container"><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div></div>
```

Comment: why doing calc in .right? couldnt you use right:0 ?

Comment: ITS WORKING FINE http://jsfiddle.net/37eayr2w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or remove the height:100% in .right.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is the answer, thanks. It seems when I put height: 100%; to the right side, its height is calculated as view height.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `display` of your divs to `inline-block;` Then the div won't be "ignoring" the stylesheet height anymore.